# App crash after removes child from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm newbie at coding. I'm having some problems while writing a dialog box code.

After clicking on the AllertDialog button, the child is removed from the firebase database, but the app crash immediately and i dont know why.
here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
  commentCreatorId = dataSnapshot.child(CommentsKey).child("commentuid").getValue().toString();

  if (currentUserID.equals(commentCreatorId))
  {
    final AlertDialog.Builder holdComent = new AlertDialog.Builder(ClickPostActivity.this);
    holdComent.setTitle("Comentário");
    holdComent.setNegativeButton("Deletar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
          {                                                
            commentsRef.child(CommentsKey).removeValue();
          }
        });

   Dialog dialog = holdComent.create();
   dialog.show();

   dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.white);
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the crash logcat please?

Comment: show your whole page code

Comment: DatabaseReference mcustomerdb= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CommentsKey").child("commentuid"); then put addvalueventlistenere on mcustomerdb.

Comment: [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) gets triggered multiple times. Why do you want to display alert dialog inside `onDataChange()` method?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @.